# Change a symbolic link's target without changing its name in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, symlink

I have a symbolic link('cur_project') in my HOME directory and want to change its destination every time i start working on any new project by just calling the SET_CUR_PROJ variable on terminal.

I've added a line in ~/.vimrc file like this:

```
SET_CUR_PROJ= "ln -sf -T $PWD $HOME/cur_project"
```

By this line i mean that whenever i call this variable it should change that symbolic to current working directory.
I am running this command as :

```
$source ~/.bashrc
$$SET_CUR_PROJ
```

Problem with this approach is it resolves the two variables $PWD and $HOME at the time of source but i need to resolve $PWD into its recent values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variables don't work like that. What you want is a function:

```
function SET_CUR_PROJ {
    ln -sf -T $PWD $HOME/cur_project
}
```

Then you invoke it with `SET_CUR_PROJ`

Answer (score 0):

Or - at the cost of invoking another process - you can do $(pwd).

Comment: This won't work i tried using :
SET_CUR_PROJ="ln -sf -T $(pwd) $HOME/cur_project"
and calling by,
$SET_CUR_PROJ. Actually,if you see $(pwd) will always give the same result.